# Union de dos array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, angular5

necesito unir dos array, desde el servidor obtengo el siguiente json. 
una array que dice "data" que tiene 2 objetos y otro que se llama "Doc" que lo componen 4 objetos.

> Quiero crear una matriz que contenga 8 elementos igual a lo siguiente (lo hice a mano):

```
[
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 1,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 2,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 3,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 4,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "iddoc": 1,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "iddoc": 2,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "iddoc": 3,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 4,
        "false": 1
    }]
```

Esto es lo que recibo del servidor en json

```
{
"status": "success",
"code": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "nombre": "Compras",
        "descripcion": "Art.-141 C.T.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "nombre": "Contribuyentes",
        "descripcion": "Artículo 141. C.T.- ",
        "estado": 1
    },

],
"Doc": [
    {
        "**iddoc**": 1,
        "documento": "CREDITO FISCAL",
        "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 2,
        "documento": "NOTA DE CREDITO",
        "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C- ",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 3,
        "documento": "FACTURA",
        "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 4,
        "documento": "NOTA DE DEBITO",
        "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C.-",
        "estado": 1
    },
       ],
"mensaje": "Todo se ha cargado correctamente"}
```

he intentado hacerlo asi:

```
this.Info = response.data;
                this.liva = response.data.filter((item) => item.estado == 1);
                this.docs = response.Doc.filter((item) => item.estado == 1);
                this.DocYlib = this.liva.map((item)=>{
                    const DocumentoUtilizado = new ModeloDocUtilizadosIVA();
                    DocumentoUtilizado.Libro = item.idlibrosiva;
                    DocumentoUtilizado.estado = false;
                    DocumentoUtilizado.documento = this.docs.map((item) => item.iddoc);
                    return DocumentoUtilizado;
                })
```

Pero el resultado a sido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que debes mejorar tu pregunta, puedes explicar mejor esta parte?: `(2 Data X 4 Doc)`  2x4=8 pero no vas a multiplicar objetos evidentemente y 2+4 = 6. No se entiende bien.

Comment: Gracias, creo que asi se es mas atendible =)

Comment: no queda  muy clara la relación entre los dos arrays, es combinar los id de docs para cada id de liva ?, el false del resultado de donde sale? es liva estado o docs estado (en este ejemplo parecen estar filtrados a 1)? es relevante copiar el estado si se filtra?

Answer (score 3):

La forma mas sencilla es usar spread separator:

```js
const a = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
const b = [{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 5}];
const c = [...a, ...b];
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

ya te dieron una solución que utiliza el operador de propagación (operador para iterables), yo te muestro una mas antigua (y por ende mas compatible) con el uso del método `concat` que sirve para unir dos arreglos:

```js
var dataJson = {
"status": "success",
"code": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "nombre": "Compras",
        "descripcion": "Art.-141 C.T.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "nombre": "Contribuyentes",
        "descripcion": "Artículo 141. C.T.- ",
        "estado": 1
    },

],
"Doc": [
    {
        "**iddoc**": 1,
        "documento": "CREDITO FISCAL",
        "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 2,
        "documento": "NOTA DE CREDITO",
        "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C- ",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 3,
        "documento": "FACTURA",
        "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 4,
        "documento": "NOTA DE DEBITO",
        "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C.-",
        "estado": 1
    },
       ],
"mensaje": "Todo se ha cargado correctamente"}

console.log(dataJson.data.concat(dataJson.Doc));
```

Answer (score 1):

no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero quizás esto te pueda ayudar para crear nuevo array juntando dos array puedes utilizar en es6

```js
var _a = [1, 2, 3];
var _b = [4, 5];
_a.push(..._b)

console.log(_a)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```